# Sequelize: SequelizeUniqueConstraintError get conflicting row

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm creating a backend using Sequelize. For best practices, I want to return Location header if the user tries to create an duplicated resource. Check my code:

```js
try {
    const resource = await Resource.create(data);
    return res.status(201).send(resource);
} catch (error) {
    // Error handling
    switch (error.name) {
        case 'SequelizeDatabaseError': return res.status(400).send(error);
        case 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError': {
          // Resource location
          res.location(`/${_location_}`)
          return res.status(409).send(_resource_)
        };
    }
```

Obs: I'm not sure if check `error.name` is the best way to get the error. Please comment others if you know.

Printing the error on the console I found the error details:

```js
{
    // ...
    ValidationErrorItem {
        message: 'name must be unique',
        type: 'unique violation',
        path: 'name',
        value: _value_,
        origin: 'DB',
        instance: [Resource],
        validatorKey: 'not_unique',
        validatorName: null,
        validatorArgs: []
      }
    ],
    fields: { name: _value_ },
    detail: 'Key (name)=(_value_) already exists.',
    // ...
}
```

Obs: `_value_` refers to duplicated value and `name` to column name.

There is a way to get the id (primary key, uuid, etc.) of the conflicting resource without do another query? If don't, should I really do the query just for return the Location header param?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried it on my local server. I don't think it is possible to get Primary key of the conflicting row.

I would suggest before making `.create()` call you make `.findOne()` query so if you found already existing entry then you can return that row so it will also prevent error while creating new entry and it will also save `create` query on Database.